# A new name or the new name?

Tags: articles

I am having trouble with articles. Here is the context:

> You are now changing your username. **A/the** new username must be different.

I think it would be just fine to just use *your* there, but I want to know which article is okay to be used there.

As it is not definite—not set yet—I think I should use *a* there, but at the same time as it is kind of *The new username (you will have happened to use) must be different*, I think I should use *the* there.

Comment: @sumelic That's better. I should edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would certainly use ***the*** here. As you say, ***your*** would also be appropriate.

I would not use ***a*** because the passage seems to be dealing with a specific situation, and in that specific situation there will only be one new name. Therefore, the name *is* implicitly already "set" at the time that you mention it. You aren't just referring to any new username — you are referring to *this particular* username that the user is about to enter.

(Sorry, I don't know if this explanation is helpful or not — as a native speaker, I'm not used to thinking about why I use articles certain ways, and I haven't studied the subject either.)

Comment: I agree. It can be read as "The new username [that you choose] must be different".

Comment: +1 Agreed. But *a* would not be ungrammatical either. It would just be something different, e.g. the beginning of a series of generally applicable rules. Consider: "You are about to have a baby. A baby requires constant care. . . ."